# firebug net monitor options

Tags: ajax, post, get, firebug

I have an issue where I executing an AJAX request. Instead of seeing the normal POST or GET preceeding the action page url, I see OPTIONS. The data is successfully posted, but there is no response from the action page. What does OPTIONS indicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "The OPTIONS method represents a
>   request for information about the
>   communication options available on the
>   request/response chain identified by
>   the Request-URI. This method allows
>   the client to determine the options
>   and/or requirements associated with a
>   resource, or the capabilities of a
>   server, without implying a resource
>   action or initiating a resource
>   retrieval."

[source](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Comment: Yes, but... why is Firefox not GETting or POSTing?

Comment: I've since learned that it is because it is a cross-site / cross-domain AJAX attempt.  You need to use $.getJSON or $.ajax to issue a JSONP request to do cross-site.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to a cross-domain AJAX attempt. Sometimes something as harmless-looking as requesting h ttp://www.example.com from h ttp://example.com can cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: this just saved my life.  I've been pulling my hair out over this for two days.

Comment: You can write http instead of h ttp, because example.com is reserved for examples.